# Incorrect Place_ID Details in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

How do I go about getting the Google Maps API Place ID details corrected?

As an example, for the `place_id = ChIJq-W618k0K4gRRJXspdvJ9ck`, I get the following Google Places API Web Service response:

```
"formatted_address" : "Toronto General Hospital, 200 Elizabeth Street, Toronto, ON M5G 2C4, Canada"
```

but it really should be returning:

```
"formatted_address" : "200 Elizabeth Street, Toronto, ON M5G 2C4, Canada"
```

The name of the building should not be included with the formatted address.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got that formatted address from the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). This API does not have a `"name"` field in the response, so the name of the hospital has nowhere to go but into the `"formatted_address"` field:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJq-W618k0K4gRRJXspdvJ9ck&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
formatted_address: "Toronto General Hospital, 200 Elizabeth Street, Toronto, ON M5G 2C4, Canada",
```

If you'd like to have the name and address in separate fields, send a Places API [Details request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJq-W618k0K4gRRJXspdvJ9ck&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
formatted_address: "200 Elizabeth Street, Toronto, ON M5G 2C4, Canada",
name: "Toronto General Hospital",
```

You will get the name in the formatted address, even in Places API, if the Place ID represents a building (`types: ["premise"]`):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJq-W618k0K4gRRJXspdvJ9ck&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
formatted_address: "Hyman Soloway, 157 Laurier Ave E, Ottawa, ON K1N 1K5, Canada"
name: "Hyman Soloway"
```

If you find this is the case with a building that doesn't have a name, but the name actually is that of a business in that building, here's how to report this problem in Google Maps:

1. Find the places in Google Maps ([Hyman Soloway](https://www.google.ch/maps/place/Hyman+Soloway,+157+Laurier+Ave+E,+Ottawa,+ON+K1N+1K5,+Canada/@45.4251394,-75.6864749,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4cce05067adf7efb:0x4e414ba0523a7574!8m2!3d45.4251119!4d-75.6841931?hl=en))
2. Click on *Add a missing place*
3. Move the name of the business from the **Address** field to **Name**
4. Fill in the rest of fields to the best of your knowledge and **Submit**

Comment: Thanks miguev.  I only use the Places API Details request.  I checked again all is good now, so not sure what changed.

Comment: I have another couple of examples were the name is being added to the formatted address no matter which method I use: ChIJwxGwXwIFzkwRl9n5DuhXPbw and ChIJ-37fegYFzkwRdHU6UqBLQU4 so I don't think it is as simple as using the correct API method.  What do you think is happening?

Comment: ChIJwxGwXwIFzkwRl9n5DuhXPbw seems to be fine, but I found ChIJ-37fegYFzkwRdHU6UqBLQU4 is a building and maybe it should be a business. I've extended this answer to include how to fix it.